# what values to use for classification using HMM

Tags: matlab

Can i use the mean and standard deviation values obtained from an image in the HSV color space for the training of a system for recognition using HMM in MATLAB?

```
%function colorMoments = colorMoments(hsv)
% image to be first converted from R, G, B to the H, S, V color space 
% input: image to be analyzed and extract 2 first moments from each H,S,V
% output: 1x6 vector containing the 2 first color momenst from each H,S,V
% channel

% load image into work space and re-size
a = imread('filename.ext');
b = imresize(a,0.079);

% convert from R,G,B to the H,S,V color space
hsv = rgb2hsv(b);

% extract color channels
H = double(hsv(:, :, 1));
S = double(hsv(:, :, 2));
V = double(hsv(:, :, 3));

% compute 2 first color moments from each channel
meanH = mean( H(:) );
stdH  = std( H(:) );
meanS = mean( S(:) );
stdS  = std( S(:) );
meanV = mean( V(:) );
stdV  = std( V(:) );

% construct output vector
colorMoments = zeros(1, 6);
colorMoments(1, :) = [meanH stdH meanS stdS meanV stdV];
end
```

Comment: Not sure how the code is relevant to the -imho- very theoretical question. I guess there are a lot of articles which can provide answers. (My intuition is: you are on the right track and HSV is preferred, but I could be wrong. Like DNN in these cases: http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/01/deep-learning-can-be-easily-fooled.html)

Comment: question is a bit broad...

Comment: You always have to pick some features which you believe allow a good separation between what you want to distinguish. If you have reasons to believe that mean and variance are characteristic features of your input images, then you will probably achieve good results.

Comment: @hbaderts thanks. i'ld rather use HOG to extract my features buh its not responding. please can u guide me through the use of blockprc?